# How do terms like $x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ enhance the ability to approximate analytical functions?

Tags: approximation

In this paper [Quantum Circuit Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00745) it wrote that the ability of a quantum circuit to approximate a function can be enhanced by terms like $x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ ($x\in[-1,1])$.
Given inputs {x,f(x)}, assume we are going to approximate an analytical function by a polynomial with higher terms up to the $n$th order, the steps are similar to the following:

1.construct a polynomial like $(1+x+\sqrt{1-x^2})^n$

2.apply a parameterized unitary transformation $U(\theta)$, and turn the polynomial into something like $(u_{i1}+u_{i2}x+u_{i3}\sqrt{1-x^2})^n$

3.minimize the cost function by tuning the parameters $\theta$ iteratively.

I am a little confused about how can terms like $x\sqrt{1-x^2}$ enhance the ability to approximate the function. Maybe it's implemented by introducing nonlinear terms, but I can't find the exact mathematical representation.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Trivially, greater space of approximating functions $\implies$ better approximations... If you are asking why *this* concrete function, a possible answer is "because *can* be (easily?) implemented by quantum circuits".